# Topology proof, interior of the set and closed sets

Tags: general-topology

I don’t know whether these exercises are pretty hard or I’m just not good enough, but there is another one I can’t do.

> Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of a topological space such that $A = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int} A)$ and $B = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int} B)$.
>
> Prove that $A \cup B = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(A \cup B))$.

If you can, don’t give me a whole answer but some advice on what I should do. (Also, in my book the fact that $A = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int} A)$ is somehow called, but I don’t know how to translate that.)

Comment: To prove that two sets $C$ and $D$ are equal, one way to proceed is to prove both that $C \subset D$ and $D \subset C$. Is there one of the inclusions that you know how to prove here?

Comment: @cs89 I can prove the inclusion of the left side in the right side

Comment: To prove that $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(A \cup B)) \subset A \cup B$, could you use the fact that $A \cup B$ is closed?

Comment: What are the definitions you use for $\text{cl}(X)$ and $\text{int}(X)$? There are multiple equivalent definitions.

Comment: @cs89 Yeah, I see it. Beacuse its interior, it’s „inside” of the A$\cup$B, then, we have Cl. Beacuse A$\cup$B is closed, it can be either equivalent or „bigger” than closure of its interior. Sorry for chaotic proof, but I got the idea

Comment: @durianice cl(X) is smallest closed set that includes X, and int(X) is the biggest set open in X. I didn’t know there are other definitions

Comment: @cs89 oh wait, I didn’t even see that I’ve just proved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you wanted hints only. I give one possible solution outline below, so feel free to read as much or as little as you need.

As usual, we can proceed by showing both inclusions; letting $C = A \cup B$ and $D = {\rm Cl} ({\rm Int} (A \cup B))$, we show $C \subseteq D$ and $D \subseteq C$.

To show the forward inclusion, consider the following facts (make sure to prove them if you have not already): (1) ${\rm Int} S \subseteq {\rm Int} (S \cup T)$ for any sets $S, T$, and (2) $S \subseteq T \implies {\rm Cl} S \subseteq {\rm Cl} T$ for any sets $S, T$. Fact (1) provides that ${\rm Int} A$ and ${\rm Int} B$ are both subsets of ${\rm Int} (A \cup B)$. Then, fact (2) provides that ${\rm Cl} ({\rm Int} A)$ and ${\rm Cl} ({\rm Int} B)$ are both subsets of ${\rm Cl} ({\rm Int} (A \cup B)) = D$. By hypothesis then, $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $D$. Since $C = A \cup B$, then it follows that $C \subseteq D$.

To show the reverse inclusion, consider the following facts (again, make sure you know why they are true): (1) ${\rm Cl} S$ is closed for any set $S$, (2) $S = {\rm Cl} S$ if $S$ is closed, and (3) ${\rm Int} S \subseteq S$ for any set $S$. Fact (1) shows that $D = {\rm Cl} ({\rm Int} (A \cup B))$ is closed; fact (2) then shows that $D \subseteq {\rm Int} (A \cup B)$. Finally, fact (3) shows that ${\rm Int} (A \cup B) \subseteq A \cup B = C$. Therefore, $D \subseteq C$.

Comment: Thank you. The guy in the comments walked me through this proof, so I kinda did it myself, but thank you anyway :)